# Wordpress category post box

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I want to create two box and in that box i want to show post from 2
categorys[in wordpress]...for example

```
     BOX 1                             BOX2

post from category 1            post from category 2
post from category 1            post from category 2
post from category 1            post from category 2
post from category 1            post from category 2
```

I know that i can create box with css and html. Is there any plugin for that?

I tried some plugins but it's not working. like :  [List category posts.](http://wordpress.org/plugins/list-category-posts/)
I have no idea how to manage that. Any ideas would be good.

Answer (score 0):

Add shortcodes for two categories, encapsulate them in div(s), set width to 50%, set them relative and float them left.